# python return matching and non-matching patterns of string

Tags: python, regex, string

I would like to split a string into parts that match a regexp pattern and parts that do not match into a list.

For example

```
import re
string = 'my_file_10'
pattern = r'\d+$'
#  I know the matching pattern can be obtained with :
m = re.search(pattern, string).group()
print m
'10'
#  The final result should be as following
['my_file_', '10']
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put parenthesis around the pattern to make it a capturing group, then use `re.split()` to produce a list of matching and non-matching elements:

```
pattern = r'(\d+$)'
re.split(pattern, string)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = 'my_file_10'
>>> pattern = r'(\d+$)'
>>> re.split(pattern, string)
['my_file_', '10', '']
```

Because you are splitting on digits at the end of the string, an empty string is included.

If you only ever expect *one* match, at the end of the string (which the `$` in your pattern forces here), then just use the `m.start()` method to obtain an index to slice the input string:

```
pattern = r'\d+$'
match = re.search(pattern, string)
not_matched, matched = string[:match.start()], match.group()
```

This returns:

```
>>> pattern = r'\d+$'
>>> match = re.search(pattern, string)
>>> string[:match.start()], match.group()
('my_file_', '10')
```

Comment: This definitely answers the original question. Now, I wonder what would be a pythonic way to figure out *which* elements in the resulting list matched, and which did not. I'd need that, and matching each element to check feels more than a little clunky.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) to make a list of those separate matches and use [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter), which filters out all elements which are considered false ( *empty strings* )

```
>>> import re
>>> filter(None, re.split(r'(\d+$)', 'my_file_015_01'))
['my_file_015_', '01']
```

Comment: good idea, but I need something that makes only two parts. For example if the string is 'my_file_015_01', your solution would give ['my_file_', '015', '_', '01']. This complicates things in my code. Martijn's answer suits better.